# Verb for "agreeing to meet"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a verb for "agreeing to meet" or "deciding to meet"? As in

> A: Would you like to get together on Friday?
>
> B: I can't, Dan and I agreed to meet (that day).

or as in

> Q: Did we agree to meet on Tuesday or Wednesday?

only less cumbersome? It doesn't really have to be a single word, but if it's not then it should be something that flows (unlike "deciding/agreeing to meet").

One possible answer is to just use the verb *meet* (or *see* or *get together* etc.), as in "I can't, I'm meeting Dan" or "Are we meeting on Tusday?". But it doesn't really mean the exact same thing; for instance, you can say "I agreed to meet him on Sunday but I plan to blow him off", where obviously "I'm meeting him on Sunday but I plan to blow him off" is somewhat nonsensical.

I hope this is an appropriate place to ask this; I've seen similar questions around here, so I thought it'd be okay.

**EDIT**

I tried to look for it in Thesauruses and dictionaries, but unsurprisingly "agree to meet" was not in entry in any of them. I googled it as well but couldn't find similar questions (at best I found definitions and synonyms of the verb "meet", at worst articles on Putin). I asked quite a few people but no one could come up with anything.

I hope this is enough... If not, I apologise.

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  
A dictionary or thesaurus may be quite helpful. Your question should include the results of your search. It should also explain why the results were not adequate to answer your question.

Comment: Wow, this is surprising. I've seen many similar questions with nothing of the sort. I will edit the post.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Which construction are you looking for: *we (agreed to meet)*, per your quotes, or *I (agreed to meet) him* as you have it later? Some words that fit one might not fit the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'make plans'. As in

> A: Would you like to get together on Friday?
>
> B: I can't, Dan and I made plans (for that day).

and

> Q: Did we make plans for Tuesday or Wednesday?

which would make

> He and I made plans for Sunday but I plan to blow him off.

Comment: Hmm... That's nice, but doesn't really have the tone I was going for. Thanks for your answer, though:]

Comment: I'll be more specific as to why this isn't what I was looking for: if you really just agreed to meet someone, and you didn't decide on what to do, it sounds a bit weird to say you "made plans" with them. Even if you did decide to just have a cup of coffee it sounds a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

***am/are to* (meet)**

Your examples would then be:

> A: Would you like to get together on Friday?
>
> B: I can't, I ***am to* meet** Dan (that day).

And:

> Q: ***Are*** we ***to* meet** on Tuesday or Wednesday?

Your additional example would be:

> I ***am to* meet** him on Sunday but I plan to blow him off

See the following (relevant extracts) from **[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be)**:

> ***be***:
>
> *present* 1st singular ***am***; 2nd singular ***are***; 3rd singular **is** ; plural ***are***
>
> verbal auxiliary:
>
> > **4** —*used with* the infinitive with ***to*** to *express* futurity, *arrangement in advance*
> > , or *obligation*
>
> Example: I ***am to*** interview him today

Comment: Less cumbersome? Perhaps. Far more clunky in conversation (which OP's examples address).

Comment: Hmm... Yes, that's a possibility. A bit too formal for a casual conversation, though. And it also sounds like *you* need to meet *Dan*, and no the other way around